# Checking For Included Class Method That Can Be Absent

Tags: ruby

I have a case where I have a class methods that are available on a class based on whether or not that class includes a module. For example:

```
class HomePage
  include Symbiont

  url_matches 'test'
end

class WeightPage
  include Symbiont
end
```

Here when Symbiont is included, it provides a class method called `url_matches`. Note, however, that you don't have to use that, as WeightPage shows. So while Symbiont makes the method available, a class that includes Symbiont does not have to utilize it.

**Here's the problem:** *What I want to do is check if the class is in fact utilizing it.*

But I can't figure out how. So let's say I do this:

```
@home = HomePage.new
@weight = WeightPage.new
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
@home.respond_to?(:url_matches)    # should return true
@weight.respond_to?(:url_matches)  # should return false
```

That does not work. Both return false. I then tried it on the class:

```
@home.class.respond_to?("url_matches")
@weight.class.respond_to?("url_matches")
```

That always returns true, however.

I tried this:

```
@home.class.public_instance_methods.include?(:url_matches)
@weight.class.public_instance_methods.include?(:url_matches)
```

Always returns false.

```
@home.class.method_defined?(:url_matches)
@weight.class.method_defined?(:url_matches)
```

Always returns false.

At this point, I'm not sure what to do.

**Underlying Code Context**

The code in context may be a bit hard to follow for purposes of this question, but just to provide it:

Here is the "Symbiont" module that gets included:

https://github.com/jnyman/symbiont/blob/master/lib/symbiont.rb

Note in particular this part:

```
module Symbiont
  def self.included(caller)
    caller.extend Symbiont::Assertion
```

The Symbiont::Assertion is here:

https://github.com/jnyman/symbiont/blob/master/lib/symbiont/assertions.rb

That is where the `url_matches` comes from. So when Symbiont is included in a class, as shown earlier, this is what allows `url_matches` to be declared on a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add that `url_matches` method to both classes just by including `Symbiont` into both of them.

That said: You are not interested into if the the class responds to that method, but if the method was called. If you look into the [implementation of that method](https://github.com/jnyman/symbiont/blob/master/lib/symbiont/assertions.rb#L10) you will see that that method sets a `@url_match` variable. Therefore you question should be: Was the `@url_match` variable set?

This can be achieved by using [`instance_variable_get`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_get):

```
@home.class.instance_variable_get(:@url_match)
@weight.class.instance_variable_get(:@url_match)
```

Comment: Not sure if that's a good idea. `@url_match` seems to be an implementation detail, that shouldn't be leaked into your code.

Comment: @Magnuss Good point, but actually the logic I'm doing here is part of another class within that code. I didn't mention that so as not to complicate things. I'm trying out the code provided in the answer provided; will update if it looks good. So far all signs are positive.

Comment: @Magnuss: I agree with you, `@url_match` is an implementation detail and it is probably a bad idea to use that variable outside of the gem. But checking that variable seems to be the only option at the moment, since the OP did not tell us why he needs to know if that method was called and since that gem does not offer another option.

Comment: This worked great! Just for context, here is the file in that code repo where I'm using this: https://github.com/jnyman/symbiont/blob/master/lib/symbiont/factory.rb. Specifically check out lines 25 and 29. The crucial point was the reorientation of my thinking in that I shouldn't check if the class method was capable of being responded to, but rather if it was called. It was my fault for not making it clear this code logic would be used inside the gem and I apologize for that.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
expect(HomePage).to respond_to(:url_matches)
```

?

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents: I guess I would patch the `url_matches` method, so that upon call, it sets a class variable `@@symbiont_enabled` to `true`, and I'd add another class method, that would look something like this:

```
def self.symbiont_enabled?
  @@symbiont_enabled
end
```

Comment: I was thinking the exact same thing